# Proper way to export to CSV?

Tags: powershell

I had a quick questions regarding exporting to CSV.

How is it decided on what to export to a CSV? What do i mean by that? The below example is just reading off a list and querying the Systemversion off AD. Then, i am associating it with the proper version we go off by. Unfortunately, it does export it properly or sometimes at all. Im not sure if this is making any sense so pardon the ignorance on my part.

```
$CStrings = Get-Content "C:\users\ME\Desktop\Comps.txt"

$comps = Foreach($Computer in $CStrings){

$VS = Get-ADComputer -Identity:"CN=$Computer,OU=MY Computers,OU=LAB " -Properties:operatingSystemVersion | Select-Object -ExpandProperty operatingsystemversion
    if($VS -like "21543"){
        "$Computer", "Version 45.32"}
        else {
    if($VS -like "21544"){
        "$Computer", "Version 45.33"}
        else{
    if($VS -like "21545"){
        "$Computer", "Version 45.34"}
        else{
        "$Computer", "$VS"
            }    
        }
    }  
}

Foreach($comp in $comps){

    Write-Output $comp | Out-File C:\users\ME\Desktop\comps.csv
     
    }
```

The result in the CSV comes out to just one version output, but nothing else. I tried `"$computer - Versions 45.32"` which joins it, and exports each computer but, its all in one column.

Before i get hounded at, i did check other forums including ms_docs lol would rather have someone dumb it down for me if possible.

Summary: Looking to keep the Computer Name, and Version in a separate Column.

Happy New Years BTW!(:

Comment: `-like` matches against the _entire_ input, so to find _substrings_ you should use something like `$VS -like '*21543*'` - otherwise, just use `-eq`. `-match`, by contrast, does perform substring matches, but the RHS is interpreted as a regex.

Comment: [1] why are you NOT using `Export-CSV`? [*grin*] ///// [2] why are you embedding an IF in an ELSE instead of using ELSEIF?

Comment: What does " it does export it properly" mean? Sample data would give us a clue

Comment: Listen guys...im just doing it the way i know. @lee i did try the `Export-CSV` but, had worse results. Ill look into ELSEIF, not familiar with is so ill look it up in MS_Docs. Thank you! Btw, the results im getting is just the version output in the CSV like such: `Versions 45.32`, it shows on the first block, and that's it. Nothing else is exported.

Comment: oh! and by proper, i mean, what is needed to export to a csv, how do you appoint those strings, etc. Idk if that makes sense. How does it know what to export onto column one, and column 2.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala - it seems that DougMaurer posted a good solution. that is how you _properly_ build a csv from inside PoSh. doing it manually is ... icky. [*grin*]

Comment: "proper", "worse results". This means absolutely nothing. No one has any idea what your actual issue is here.

Comment: its already been answered, buddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the easiest ways is to create a list of custom objects and then simply export that list to csv. Here is one way to do that with your current requirements.

```
$CStrings = Get-Content "C:\users\ME\Desktop\Comps.txt"

$comps = Foreach($Computer in $CStrings)
{
    $VS = Get-ADComputer -Identity:"CN=$Computer,OU=MY Computers,OU=LAB " -Properties operatingSystemVersion | Select-Object -ExpandProperty operatingsystemversion

    $VS = switch -regex ($VS)
    {
        '21543' {"Version 45.32"}
        '21544' {"Version 45.33"}
        '21545' {"Version 45.34"}
        default {$_}
    }

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ComputerName = $Computer
        OSVersion    = $VS
    }
}

$comps | Export-Csv -Path C:\users\ME\Desktop\comps.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: hmm, this works for the most part except that its not switching. It just outputs `'21543'` instead of `"Version 45.32"`, is there a reason for that? Can you explain to me whats going on with the `switch -regex` portion and below? Looking to understand it better so i don't have to keep asking on here lol

Comment: figured it out after looking more into the switch operator with, `Get-Help about_Switch -Full`. Turns out `-regex` will try to match the value, which is why it was erroring out; hence why i used `-like` instead of `-match`, due to the value not matching exactly even thought the output is just that. Weird. Anyways, thank you and to everyone else that commented, ive looked into everything that was mentioned! Summary to answer: took off the -regex